# How to identify all x co-ordinate values for a certain y value from the mathplot in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, audio, scipy

I have plotted a frequency vs time graph of a audio wav extracted from a video using matplotlib and scipy.

Now I want to identify all the values of time(x-coordinate) for a certain value(like zero, peak positive frequency,..,etc,.) of frequency(y-coordinate).
Here is my code for plotting :

```
sr, signal = wavfile.read(wave_file_path)

y = signal[:, 0] 
t = np.arange(len(y)) / float(sr)

plt.plot(t, y)
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('y')
#plt.show()
plt.save("myplot.png")
```

I tried `(np.interp(0, Signal,time))`but that's only giving the first zero frequency value of time but not the whole list of y co-ordinate values. Just to mention, I also tried `print(np.where(t == 0.0))` which I'm not sure if that's the correct way of using it because I only got  `(array([0]),)` as result for every wav file.
[image: Here is a graph I have plotted from an audio file]

Here is a graph I have plotted from an audio file.
I saved the plot instead of viewing because I am using a linux server with no GUI. 
If there is a simpler way via GUI then I can try that too.

Comment: Can you share at least some of the contents of `y` and `t`, or the wave files? That’s probably where the answer is going to be found, right? I don’t imagine that matplotlib will be of much use for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [@Alexander Cécile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11301900/alexander-c%C3%A9cile).Yes, I was very late figuring that out. I have managed to get the values I desired through the index's of `y` and `t` lists. I was just making an operation of basic list iteration complicated with the use of matplotlib.

I got the idea of using mathplotlib as everyone I found dealing with scipy are using mathplotlib to plot their points(peaks,+ve peaks,...etc,.) which isn't my use case at all. I feel so dumb for posting this question without any critical thought,not sure if I should delete this question so I'm answering it instead of commenting.